# Trigger drone tag event with api?

Tags: drone.io

I'm using the [drone downstream](http://plugins.drone.io/drone-plugins/drone-downstream/) plugin and it doesn't appear to be able to trigger a tag event in the downstream repo, only push. From there I was looking into the drone api to determine if I can hit the api to trigger a tag, but I'm not seeing it in docs or [drone-go](https://github.com/drone/drone-go) code. I'm afraid I'm missing it somewhere obvious, anyone know if you can trigger tag event in drone through api?

drone downstream plugin config:

```
pipeline:
trigger:
  when:
    event: [push, tag]
    branch: master
  image: plugins/downstream
  server: https://drone6.company.com
  fork: true
  repositories:
    - org/cars-v1
  secrets: [ downstream_token ]
```

Comment: Can you post your downstream plugin config in here and double check you have the tag events active/checked in drone settings?

Comment: Sure! Updated post

Comment: it's look good can't spot anything wrong, did you check if you repository is setup to work with `tag` events? You click the top right menu and go to Settings you will see the option  https://imgur.com/xNhVozk

Comment: Yup, both the upstream and downstream repos have tag configured. Unfortunately it seems no matter what event the upstream is triggered with, it triggers a push in downstream repo. I may just need to PR the plugin